# string to binary[]

Tags: c#, stream

I have a string I need to feed to a com object that has a LoadFromStream method accepting "object Data". I'm guessing this should be a byte[].

Rather basic question:
I got my MemoryStream all filled and ready to go. What's the best way to convert it to binary[]?
Should I manually read it into the array one by one or is there an easy built in way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MemoryStream has a ToArray() method which returns a byte[].

Comment: Doh, once again I miss the obvious :P